# Finding what's selected in HubSection GridView DataTemplate

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have the following code that makes up a `HubSection` within a `Hub`.

```
            <HubSection DataContext="{Binding Path=[0], Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}" Padding="40,30,40,0">
            <HubSection.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/BG.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </HubSection.Background>
            <HubSection.Header>
                <TextBlock x:Uid="Section1Header" TextLineBounds="TrimToBaseline" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" Text="English"/>
            </HubSection.Header>
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView
                    x:Name="itemGridView1"
                    Margin="-4,-4,0,0"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard240x320ItemTemplate}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
                </GridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

I have an AppBar set up as well, but I'm not sure how to tell the AppBar what is selected in the HubSection.

Please advise.

Edit: To clarify, I'm facing issues with implementing code such as `itemGridView1.selectedItem` because I'm being told it "does not exist in the current context".

Answer (score 2):

Most of the advice regarding this issue centres on iterating through the visual tree of your Frame, but that doesn't seem to work well in the XAML Hub Section.

Instead, implement a SelectionChanged event in your GridView. When this is triggered, it will send details of the GridView sender, which can then be referenced for additional information such as .SelectedItem.

```
private void GridViewName_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var GridState = sender as GridView;
    if(GridState.SelectedItems.Count>0)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow this event wasn't firing work for me and i am forced to changed to ItemClick event...